# Add function to Object with an element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events

I have an Object

```
function Object(name, button) {
    this.name = name;
    this.button = button;
    var alert = function () {
        alert("x");
    };
}

var ExampleOne = new Object('Example One', $('.exampleButton'));
```

How can I make the function inside the object fire on an event of Object[button]...

Using -

```
ExampleOne.button.click(function () {
    ExampleOne.alert();
});
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkqd4q5o/ - make sure that when you assign that selector, the DOM has been parsed.

Comment: `var alert` is a local variable... if you want to access it from your new object, declare with `this` - http://jsfiddle.net/qow3qu0m/2/

Comment: tymeJV - what if i just used function alert(){...});

Comment: -_- sorry guys. JS Objects 101! I'll edit question to make it more readable in case any more noobs show up with the same question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Want to answer it, tymeJV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var alert = function` is a local function and cannot be accessed outside that object. If you want it to be accessible with new instances, declare it with `this`:

```
function Object(name, button) {
    this.name = name;
    this.button = button;
    this.alert = function () {
        alert("x");
    };
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qow3qu0m/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Check your code again. Maybe you forgot to include jQuery?

```
ExampleOne.button.click(function(e) {
  alert('success!');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyGpLz